# Why the same HashPartitioner applied on two RDDs with same keys doesn't partition equally

Tags: apache-spark, join, rdd, partitioning, shuffle

I have two RDDs with same keys and different values.
I call on both of them the same `.partitionBy(partitioner)`
and then I join them:

```scala
val partitioner = new HashPartitioner(partitions = 4)

val a = spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(Seq(
  (1, "A"), (2, "B"), (3, "C"), (4, "D"), (5, "E"), (6, "F"), (7, "G"), (8, "H")
)).partitionBy(partitioner)

val b = spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(Seq(
  (1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c"), (4, "d"), (5, "e"), (6, "f"), (7, "g"), (8, "h")
)).partitionBy(partitioner)

println("A:")
a.foreachPartition(p => {
  p.foreach(t => print(t + " "))
  println()
})

println("B:")
b.foreachPartition(p => {
  p.foreach(t => print(t + " "))
  println()
})

println("Join:")
a.join(b, partitioner)
  .foreachPartition(p => {
    p.foreach(t => print(t + " "))
    println()
})
```

I get:

```
A:
(2,B) (3,C) (4,D) (6,F) (7,G) 
(8,H) (1,A) 
(5,E) 

B:
(3,c) (7,g) 
(1,a) (5,e) 
(2,b) (6,f) 
(4,d) (8,h) 

Join:
(6,(F,f)) (1,(A,a)) (2,(B,b)) (5,(E,e)) (4,(D,d)) (8,(H,h)) 
(3,(C,c)) (7,(G,g))
```

So the first question is why are A and B partitions different and why joinRDD is different from both of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partitioning is exactly the same in all cases. The problem is the method you use. Remember that each partition is processed in a separate thread. If you run this code multiple times, you'll see that the output is actually non-deterministic.

Try for example something like this instead:

```scala
a.glom.collect.map(_.mkString(" ")).foreach(println)
```

```
(4,D) (8,H)
(1,A) (5,E)
(2,B) (6,F)
(3,C) (7,G)
```

```scala
b.glom.collect.map(_.mkString(" ")).foreach(println)
```

```
(4,d) (8,h)
(1,a) (5,e)
(2,b) (6,f)
(3,c) (7,g)
```

```scala
a.join(b).glom.collect.map(_.mkString(" ")).foreach(println)
```

```
(4,(D,d)) (8,(H,h))
(1,(A,a)) (5,(E,e))
(6,(F,f)) (2,(B,b))
(3,(C,c)) (7,(G,g))
```

Note that the order of values in each partition can still be non-deterministic if executed in non-`local` context, but content of each partition will be the same as shown above.